# Is it possible to call MySQL Stored procedure from Oracle database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

So there are MySQL Database and Oracle Database. Is it possible to somehow connect to MySQL database from Oracle and call stored procedure with parameters?

Comment: [This answer at Ask TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9532855900346184780) might be useful. [Docs for DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH are located here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_hspass.htm). Note: here there be dragons. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hs2n](https://hs2n.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/oracle-create-database-link-to-mysql-database/) has a very good answer for your problem. I would check him out.